# How to create a bash alias on OS X?

Tags: terminal, bash

I want to create a bash alias on OS X, because I need to type on a really large command.

I've found some answers about the same issue on ubuntu, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias), but they mention the ~/.bashrc file, which doesn't exist (at least by default) on OS X.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found that I can do this by editing the `.bash_profile` file.

Just added:

`alias my_alias='cd /my/really/long/long/path`

to `.bash_profile`, and after reopening bash my alias command worked just fine.

Comment: Alternatively, run `source ~/.bash_profile` in the same terminal window to apply the changes without having to close the window.

Answer (score 2):

1. `nano ~/.bash_profile`
2. `alias my_alias= 'ssh username@xxxx.xxx.xx.x'`
3. ctrl + x , then press y and enter to save.
4. Don't forget to reload the file with:

   `source ~/.bash_profile`or . ~/.bash_profile
5. Then test the alias.