# Any way to create custom terminal keywords?

Tags: macos, terminal, big-sur

I want to know if it's possible to create keywords (similar to workflow keywords in alfred) for certain terminal commands. For example instead of typing:

```
php artisan serve
```

I want to type:

```
pas
```

while executing the above command.

Comment: Make alias or function in appropriate rc file.

Comment: Alias is the way to go. Just a small tip. I find the following very convenient: Every system modification that I make including aliases, custom shell scripts or executables, I store in Documents folder structure, for example: ./Documents/Commands/myCustomCommand. This way your own custom work is safely stored in the cloud and makes migration and life a little bit easier.

Comment: Why does putting it in $HOME/Documents mean it's stored in the cloud, or that it would be "safe" if it were?

Comment: If you have iCloud account, documents folder can be synced with Apple's cloud storage. Are we discussing why cloud services are safe way to store documents? https://www.apple.com/icloud/ iCloud is built into every Apple device. That means all your stuff — photos, files, notes, and more — is safe, up to date, and available wherever you are.

Comment: @Gintaras It's certainly well worth considering what would happen if a HD/SSD or machine died, and ensuring that you wouldn't lose anything important. (But iCloud is far from the only way to achieve that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ‘alias’ command defines aliases.

```
alias pas="php artisan serve"
```

The default shell is now zsh so you define this in ~/.zshrc.
Source the file `. ~/.zshrc` for the change to take effect in the current shell.

[Previously, you would define this in ~/.bash_profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180060/37797). If you updated from an older version of macOS and haven’t changed your shell from bash to zsh as prompted, you’ll still need to use ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: My life just got so much simpler. Thanks :-)